# как привязать стрелки Slick слайдера к определенным элементам на странице?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, slider, slick.js

как привязать стрелки Slick слайдера к определенным элементам на странице? например как на фото, кнопки имеют свой `:hover`, заменить стрелки на просто изображениям так

```
prevArrow: '<img  src="../images/sprites/left-btn.png">',
nextArrow: '<img  src="./images/sprites/right-btn.png">',
```

я смог, а от чтоб привязать к именно елементу как?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете обычный div со стилями , потом добавляете этот класс в prevArrow и nextArrow

```
 $('.test').slick({
        prevArrow: '.название класса',
        nextArrow: '.название класса',
 });
```